# How to implement a Digital River?

Tags: c, loops

A digital river is a sequence of numbers where every number is followed by the same number plus the sum of its digits.

I have a logical problem and I can't figure out how to loop my code so that it will do something 20 times.

First Number => KUL_digitsum = sum = 6 => KUL_NEXTRIVERNUM = 123 + 6 = 129 => KUL_Digitsum * 20

[Exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/em5sP.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "KuL_RiverFkt.h"

int main()
{
    int num;
    printf("Eingabe der Zahl: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    KUL_NextRiverNum(KUL_digitsum(num), num);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        KUL_NextRiverNum(KUL_digitsum(num), num);
        KUL_digitsum(KUL_NextRiverNum(KUL_digitsum(num), num));
    }
    return 0;
}

int KUL_digitsum(int num) 
{
    int sum = 0;
    while (num > 0) {
        int digit = num % 10;
        sum = sum + digit;
        num = num / 10;
    }
    printf("Die Summe der Zahl = %d\n", sum);
    return sum;
}

int KUL_NextRiverNum(int KUL_digitsum, int num)
{
    int summe = 0;
    summe = num + KUL_digitsum;
    printf("Die Nächste Riverzahl ist: %d\n", summe);
    return summe;
}
```

Comment: Your code ignores the return values of the `KUL_*` functions, especially the next number. Unrelated: I suggest to move the `printf`s out of the `KUL_*` functions into `main`.

Comment: Are you allowed to use arrays?

Comment: @Bodo I have to writte it in these functions thats part of the exercise aswell.

Comment: @ryyker yes I'am allowed to use arrays

Comment: .... with arrays then there are opportunities to simplify the way successive values are stored, and output, i.e. in a loop...   `for(int i = 0; i< 20; i++) ( array[i] = some_local_result;)`...

Comment: @LukasKunkal Mixing calculation and I/O is bad design. You could produce the same output by printing the return value in `main`.

Comment: The image is text that could sensibly be in the question.  It explains what a "Digital River" is quite clearly, and also explains what "River K" is and illustrates with some examples.  Ideally, the question should be self-contained, so this information should be in the question.  I find the paragraph of this question that currently reads "First Number => KUL_digitsum = sum = 6 > KUL_NEXTRIVERNUM = 123 + 6 = 129 => KUL_Digitsum * 20" inscrutable, even after reading the assignment in the image.

Comment: Note that the diagnostic print in `KUL_DigitSum()` is not great — it should report both the input (`num`) and the output (`sum`) so that you can validate that the sum is correct for the input number.  For example, `printf("Die Quersumme der Zahl %d ist %d\n", num, sum);` — if Google Translate can be trusted.  (In English: `printf("The sum of the digits of number %d is %d\n", num, sum);`). This is a general guideline for diagnostic printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is overly complicated and you ignore the return value of `KUL_NextRiverNum`.

The `KUL_*` functions themselves are correct, but they shouldn't do any printing unless you put the printfs for debugging reasons.

You want this:

```
int main()
{
  int num;
  printf("Eingabe der Zahl: ");
  scanf("%d", &num);

  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    num = KUL_NextRiverNum(KUL_digitsum(num), num);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: oh now I understand it. You put the return value into the num variabel and now the valuas inside the function are changing. Any idea how I can writte the numbers in one line? Do I need an array for this?

Comment: _"Any idea how I can writte the numbers in one line? Do I need an array for this?"_: no, you don't nead an array. Just remove all `printf`s in the `KUL_*functions` and put just one `printf` at the end of the `for` loop: `printf("%d ", num);`

Comment: that's interesting but in order to writte other text in front i have to save the numbers as a string and then print it out after the loop?

Comment: @LukasKunkal I'm not sure what you mean. Maybe you should ask another question about that exact issue.

Comment: I want to achive that the output looks like this. Die Riverzahlen sind: {num1,num2,num3...}

Comment: There are several ways to achieve this.  One is to store the numbers as they are generated into an array and then print that array.  The other is to print the preamble (`"Die Riverzaheln sind: {"`) before generating any numbers, then to add each number to the output in turn (avoiding newlines until you're done).  What should you do if the river starts at 6,319,221 so that 20 numbers don't fit on an 80-column line?  There are advantages to printing it all on a long line — computers don't mind them — not the least of which is that it is easiest.  Or track the output length and add newlines.

Answer (score 1):

- Just comment the `printf()` in those functions and alter the main like :

```c
#define MAX_RIVER_TERMS 20

//    KUL_NextRiverNum(KUL_digitsum(num), num);

    for (int i=0; i < MAX_RIVER_TERMS; i++) {
        if (i) printf (", ");
        printf ("%d", num);
        num = KUL_NextRiverNum(KUL_digitsum(num), num);
//        KUL_digitsum(KUL_NextRiverNum(KUL_digitsum(num), num));
    }
```

- Use `#define` macro values instead of magic numbers in the sources.
- Declare/qualify arguments as `const` if they're not being modified inside the function.

```c
int KUL_NextRiverNum(const int KUL_digitsum, const int num) {}
```

Comment: There is little to no benefit in const-qualifying simple values like `const int num`.   The const qualifier is important with arrays and pointers, though.  There you should use const-qualification.