# Find Digital Rivers that have a meeting point

Tags: arrays, c, compare

I currently have a problem to solve that was given to us from our teacher. I'm completly new into C and coding in general:

A digital river is a sequence of numbers where every number is followed
by the same number plus the sum of its digits. In such a sequence 123 is
followed by 129 (since 1 + 2 + 3 = 6), which again is followed by 141.

Task:
Digital rivers can meet. This happens when two digital rivers share the
same values. River 32 meets river 47 at 47, while river 471 meets river 480
at 519.
Read a number N from stdin and print all rivers which meet at this number.

I currently have this code that does the calculation for the digital river.
I really dont know how to continue.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int digitsum(int n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
        int digit = n % 10;
        sum = sum + digit;
        n = n / 10;
    }
    return sum;
}

int nextnum(int digitsum, int n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    sum = n + digitsum;
    printf("%d\n", sum);
    return sum;
}


int main()
{
  int n;
  printf("N--> ");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    n = nextnum(digitsum(n), n);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

If i put in N --> 32, it should print out all the Digital Rivers that meet the river of 32 at some point. Lets say we limit it to input of 500. Should i create arrays for everything starting with 1 and then compare the arrays ? Maybe i am thinking to complicated and you guys have a hint.

It should look like this:

```
N--> 32
{5,10,11,13,17,25,32,37,47.......}
{10,11,13,17,25,32,37,47.............}
{11,13,17,25,32,37,47................}
{13,17,25,32,37,47...................}
....
{32,37,47............................}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's a digital river and why river 471 meets river 480 at 519? The only think that can be inferred from your post is that you generate a sequence from a number by adding to it the sum of its digits and repeating the process. By the expected results you list, most likely you need to figure out a way (mathematically) to go backwards also.

Comment: @kikon makes a good point. Working backwards is probably the best way to solve the problem. The sum of the digits will always be small, so there aren't that many numbers that can immediately precede a given number. For example, only 498 and 507 precede 519. The way to compute that is to first note that the maximum sum for a three-digit number is 9+9+9, so numbers less than 519-27=492 can't possibly reach 519 in one step. Which means that only `49x`, `50x`, and `51x` need to be checked, where `x` is an unknown digit. The solution for `49x` is `(519 - 490 - (4+9)) / 2 = 8` giving 498.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72045970/5382650

Comment: @user3386109 I realize now that going backwards is far more complicated that I previously thought, since there might be *more unrelated previous values for the same number*, that is there might be several numbers whose next number is the same. For instance for 519 there are two: 498 and 507. 507 is also the next for both 492 and 501. So, a comprehensive forward search, keeping the data of visited numbers and starting solutions in arrays, as suggested by the OP might be the safer and easier solution.

Comment: @kikon I suppose you are right if the input is limited to numbers up to 500.

Comment: Do you notice that each succeeding value in the first row becomes the leftmost value in the subsequent rows? These are all the same river... Perhaps this might get interesting when there are 4+ digits in the number to play with, but for small numbers the palette is too limited to actually be interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, going backwards is a complicated algorithm to determine.  So, as a compromise method, with the parameters of not having entry values over 500, I added a function to start at "1" and build a river to see if it meets the value entered by the user.  Also, to print the river out linearly, I added a helper function to do that.  With those additional qualifications in place, following is a revised version that hunts down rivers that start and meet the entered river.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int digitsum(int n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    if (n < 10)         /* Function was not picking up any starting values under 10 */
        return n;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        int digit = n % 10;
        sum = sum + digit;
        n = n / 10;
    }
    return sum;
}

int nextnum(int digitsum, int n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    sum = n + digitsum;

    return sum;
}

void print_river(int x)
{
    if (x <= 500)
    {
        printf("%d ", x);
    }
    while (x < 500)
    {
        x = nextnum(digitsum(x), x);
        if (x <= 500)
        {
            printf("%d ", x);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void preceding(int x)
{
    int z = 0;
    for (int j = 1; j < x; j++)
    {
        z = j;

        for (int k = 0; k < x; k++)
        {
            z = digitsum(z) + z;
            if (z >= x)
            {
                if (z == x)
                {
                    print_river(j);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("N--> ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    preceding(n);
    print_river(n);

    while (n < 500)
    {
        n = nextnum(digitsum(n), n);
        print_river(n);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The function preceding starts at "1" and continues to locate meeting rivers up to the entered value.  The function print_river produces the printed output for each river.  Additional cosmetic tests were added to only print values up to 500.

Following is a sample of the terminal output for river "32".

```
@Una:~/C_Programs/Console/River/bin/Release$ ./River 
N--> 32
5 10 11 13 17 25 32 37 47 58 71 79 95 109 119 130 134 142 149 163 173 184 197 214 221 226 236 247 260 268 284 298 317 328 341 349 365 379 398 418 431 439 455 469 488 
10 11 13 17 25 32 37 47 58 71 79 95 109 119 130 134 142 149 163 173 184 197 214 221 226 236 247 260 268 284 298 317 328 341 349 365 379 398 418 431 439 455 469 488 
11 13 17 25 32 37 47 58 71 79 95 109 119 130 134 142 149 163 173 184 197 214 221 226 236 247 260 268 284 298 317 328 341 349 365 379 398 418 431 439 455 469 488 
13 17 25 32 37 47 58 71 79 95 109 119 130 134 142 149 163 173 184 197 214 221 226 236 247 260 268 284 298 317 328 341 349 365 379 398 418 431 439 455 469 488 
17 25 32 37 47 58 71 79 95 109 119 130 134 142 149 163 173 184 197 214 221 226 236 247 260 268 284 298 317 328 341 349 365 379 398 418 431 439 455 469 488 
25 32 37 47 58 71 79 95 109 119 130 134 142 149 163 173 184 197 214 221 226 236 247 260 268 284 298 317 328 341 349 365 379 398 418 431 439 455 469 488 
32 37 47 58 71 79 95 109 119 130 134 142 149 163 173 184 197 214 221 226 236 247 260 268 284 298 317 328 341 349 365 379 398 418 431 439 455 469 488 
37 47 58 71 79 95 109 119 130 134 142 149 163 173 184 197 214 221 226 236 247 260 268 284 298 317 328 341 349 365 379 398 418 431 439 455 469 488 
47 58 71 79 95 109 119 130 134 142 149 163 173 184 197 214 221 226 236 247 260 268 284 298 317 328 341 349 365 379 398 418 431 439 455 469 488 
58 71 79 95 109 119 130 134 142 149 163 173 184 197 214 221 226 236 247 260 268 284 298 317 328 341 349 365 379 398 418 431 439 455 469 488 
71 79 95 109 119 130 134 142 149 163 173 184 197 214 221 226 236 247 260 268 284 298 317 328 341 349 365 379 398 418 431 439 455 469 488 
79 95 109 119 130 134 142 149 163 173 184 197 214 221 226 236 247 260 268 284 298 317 328 341 349 365 379 398 418 431 439 455 469 488 
95 109 119 130 134 142 149 163 173 184 197 214 221 226 236 247 260 268 284 298 317 328 341 349 365 379 398 418 431 439 455 469 488
```

The listing continues past value "95" but I did not want to insert all of it into this text.

Give that a try and see if it meets the spirit of your project.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This looks really really good. I still have one problem. The River from lets say 32 should also stop with 32. I may be able to figure that out myself. Huge thanks to you